# Only require password once to decrypt files at different times?

Tags: php, encryption

User's content is encrypted, but needs to be decrypted. There are multiple files that need decryption to be viewed, and they will definitely not be viewed at the same time.

I am currently encrypting by using the user's plaintext password to encrypt a randomly-generated key, which encrypts the user's data. The password is hashed and verified normally before doing anything. I am using PHP's aes-128-gcm openssl_encrypt() function.

My current system requires a password *every time* the user wants to read a file.

I have thought about decrypting all of the content at one, but this doesn't scale well. I have also thought about storing the user's key as a cookie, but I'm worried about security.

Is there a standard way to do this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The first thing to do is separate the users password out of this.  You'll have to decrypt and re-encrypt all their files. There may be other ways around this such as allowing only new files to use this system.  But that is very use case specific, such as how long do you keep their files, what is the turn over on them etc..

In any case this is a way to do that:

1. Encrypt the files they submit using a password you generate.
2. Store this password in another file we'll call it `key.txt` for now.  Encrypt this file using the users password.
3. When user logs in (if they don't have it stored) take their password, decrypt `key.txt` and get the generated password.
4. Now you can save this generated password anywhere you want, without affecting the users account.
5. What they see (the end user experience) will look like always they go to downlaod a file, put their password in and get the file.  They wont ever know you did this, which is nice for them.

So problem one is fixed.

> Now where should we store this?

You could simply store it on the server in the DB.  This sort of depends on how confidential the data is, and how secure your server is.  Your ultimately responsible for the security of someone else's data, at least this way you can control it.

Make a table with these fields

```
  user_id | ip | password | last_access
```

When a user goes to download a file, check their last access time and IP address to invalidate the password and make them refresh it.  This is very easy to setup and totally under your control.  If you save the encryption key, it will always have some level of vulnerability at least this way its all under your control.

Even if you don't want to store it in your DB, the biggest disadvantage here is if someone gets a hold of that table, but if they do that and your storing important data you probably have plenty of problems already.

At least use the first part as that solves a big problem with tying this to their actual account password.  Even if a hacker gets the file password from the client (stolen cookies etc.) because it's separate, having that alone wont let them login to your site like the account password would.  I am assuming here, a user must login to even get to the download part.  Using the same password for both gives them them access to both the means of the getting this data and the method to download it.

To be clear, their is an argument to be made about storing it on the client side. Then if your site is compromised there is less chance someone could get a hold of the password as it (depending how you do it) only exist in memory on both the client and server etc.  It puts the responsibility on them.

**ASYMMETRIC ENCRYPTION**

You could also use asymmetric encryption. Currently it looks you are using AES, which is fine, but it's a Symmetric Key block cypher.  Basically there are three common forms of "encryption" (in vernacular):

1. Hashing (which really isn't encryption) - `md5`, `sha1`, `sha256` - these are one way, can't be decoded. They have fixed lengths, and always encrypt to the same thing.  It's common to see this for file checksum (for validating the contents of the file), Block Chain, Passwords or anything else where you need to compare two "encrypted" values.
2. Symmetric - `AES`, `3DES`, `Blowfish`, `Twofish` - anything you need to encrypt and decrypt.  The same key can do both.  Generally these will encrypt the same thing to different values each time, because of the IV.
3. Asymmetric - `SSL`, `DSA`, `RSA`, `PGP`, used in Crypto currency wallets, TLS etc. With these you have 2 keys, a public one and a private one. The keys cannot decrypt their own encrypted data, only the other key can.  So with this if you have one key on the server and the client has the other.  You can encrypt their files using your key (decryptable by only their key) and you don't have to worry so much about someone getting your key as it won't allow them to decrypt the files.  You can give one key to the client, who can use that key to decrypt their data you encrypted (even without your key).  These also encrypt to different "Stuff" each time you use them.

So you can see Asymmetric form has a few advantages to use in a two(or more) party system.  It also has the benefit that you don't need their key to encrypt a file.  All you need is your part of the pair. So for example if you generate data for them and wan't to encrypt and later have them decrypt it with the same system, you can do that with no issues.  This probably eliminates a step, as you would need to ask them, or keep track of their Symmetric anytime you wanted to encrypt something.  Here you just need your part of the key pair.

It really isn't much harder to implement (on the server), its just harder to understand what it does.  That's why I decided to add this, without this knowledge (which you may or may not already know) it's hard to use these terms and have them make sense. The only real disadvantage for you (if you call it that) if you used Asymmetric encryption, is if a client loses their key you would have no way to decrypt the file. So I would make sure they know to back them up in a secure place. It's the same problem that you see in the news when it comes to losing a crypto currency wallet which is encrypted Asymmetrically

As I said most of my knowledge has to do with encrypting and dealing with data on a server.  So I am not sure how to tie that in to the "client experience".  I do know for example how to use RSA keys for password less login for SSH etc.  Which is kind of the same thing but not quite.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

> they will definitely not be viewed at the same time

Wouldn't the most secure answer here be to simply require the password every time? I would assume (although I'm sure this isn't the answer you're looking for) that simply asking for the password each time *might* be the best solution.
Although it may be tedious for the user, I would also assume it imparts some sense of security - since it's not quite as simple as logging in (as the files are encrypted).

From my perspective, I would argue that *encrypted files* should not be mass decrypted anyways?

Sorry, I know this isn't the answer you're looking for - but if you have more information about your motivation, maybe then a more reasonable solution can be found?

Comment: The user logs in to view their files. From the user's viewpoint, they've already logged in and shouldn't need to put in their password every time. But I do agree that decrypting ALL of the information is not the best solution, which is why i'm considering the cookie instead.

Answer (score 0):

Don't do decryption on the server-side - do it client side.  It is safe to keep the user's password in memory on their own device.

Comment: Any suggestions on how to do that.  I'm just curios most of what I do lives on the server, so I am not as familiar with this topic as it relates to the client side.   I agree keeping it in memory if possible is probably the safest way to store it.

Comment: I'd like to reiterate the question that @ArtisticPhoenix asked. I agree that doing the decryption client-side is probably the best solution for my type of situation, but I haven't been able to find a js library for it. I'm weighing the possibility of doing it server-side, but I just don't know how secure the https connection is between the server and client, any insight into that?

Comment: HTTPS/TLS is pretty secure, minus the occasional HeartBleed (bug/exploit). Its probably as secure a transport layer your going to get to the client over the web which is why it's so widely used. TLS uses Asymmetric encryption, what that is is a Public Private key pair. Each Key can encrypt but not decrypt its own stuff. So the public key can decrypt stuff from the private key and the private key can decrypt stuff from the public key but not their own.   I thought of suggesting this as a way for you to encrypt the files too.  [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public-key_cryptography)

Comment: The only real disadvantage for you (if you call it that) if you used Asymmetric encryption, is if a client loses their key you would have no way to decrypt the file.  So I would make sure they know to back them up in a secure place.  It's the same problem that you see in the news when it comes to losing a crypto currency wallet which is encrypted Asymmetrically. Such as.  `Access to Quadriga CX’s digital “wallets” -- an application that stores the keys to send and receive cryptocurrencies -- appears to have been lost with the passing of Quadriga CX Chief Executive Officer in India` = 200Mil